# Trying to use the unix command 'find' to find all files checked into RCS

Tags: unix, find, rcs

I am trying to use the find command to find all of the files that are checked into RCS from my home directory. This includes files that end in things like `c,v`. When I run the commands such as

```
find . -name \*v 
find . -name \*c,v
```

this is close to the way I want and will give me files looking like

```
./LABTECH/RCSlab/trig/RCS/main.c,v
```

This is great except if I for some reason have a random file on my computer that ends in a v or in c,v that isn't in RCS, it is going to return that, too. Things like  `find . -name \*RCS\*c,v` do not work and return nothing. `find . -name RCS\*` will return the RCS directory, but none of the files inside the RCS directory.

Is there someway I can get a find command to return all files that are in RCS directories, starting from my home directory. I know I can filter out unwanted files afterwards, but it needs to only be showing me files from the RCS directory to begin with.

After reading all the answers I decided that assuming ,v are RCS files is the best way to go about this because we have not covered scripting for my teacher to ask us a question like that. We are not supposed to pipe into xargs or grep for the question either,and -path does not work on my version of unix. It was helpful to know from perreal that using -name does not allow me to match '/' which clears up some other questions I had but did not ask. I have come to the understanding that there is no way to do this without -path or some type of following command or script. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work on the presumption that if the file name ends `,v`, it is an RCS file.  Any interlopers that are not should be few and far between.

```
find $HOME -name '*,v'
```

If you are consistent about using an RCS sub-directory, then you can use the POSIX [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) option `-path` to track down files in RCS sub-directories with:

```
find $HOME -path '*/RCS/*,v'
```

If you must identify actual RCS files, then you'll need to run some program (script) to validate that the files really are RCS files:

```
find $HOME -name '*,v' -exec rcsfiles {} +
```

where `rcsfiles` is a hypothetical script that echos the names of the arguments it is given that actually are RCS files.  I would use the `rlog` command to identify whether the file is an RCS file or not.  The `rcs` command doesn't have a no-op operation that will validate an RCS file.  The `rcsfiles` script might well be as simple as:

```
for file in "$@"
do
     if rlog "$file" >/dev/null 2>&1
     then echo "$file"
     fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
find . -path '*/RCS/*,v'
```

If your version of `find` lack the `-path` option, you can test :

```
find . -name '*,v' -print | grep -E 'RCS/[^/]+,v$'
```

Comment: Normally, the RCS directory immediately precedes the file name, so you'd write `-path '*/RCS/*,v'` to identify the RCS files.

Answer (score 0):

From `find` [man-page](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Base-Name-Patterns.html):

```
-name pattern
       Because the leading directories are removed, the file names
       considered for a match with -name will never include a slash, 
       so `-name a/b' will never match anything (you probably need 
       to  use -path instead).
```

So you can use `-path` instead of `-name` as in sputnick's answer. Another way is first finding the relevant directories:

```
find -name '*RCS' -type d | xargs -n1 -I{} find {} -name '*.c,v'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name '*,v' | grep /RCS/
```

This will find all files whose names end in `,v` that are under a directory named `RCS`.

If you want to be sure they're *immediately* under an `RCS` directory:

```
find . -type f -name '*,v' | grep '/RCS/[^/]*$'
```

This ensures that there are no additional `/` characters after the `/RCS/`.

Note that CVS also uses the `,v` suffix (and the same file format) and does not use a special directory name for its repository files; it uses a `CVS` directory, but that's created when you checkout files, and it only contains a handful of metadata files. If you're not using CVS on your system, that probably won't be an issue. If you're using both RCS and CVS, the above should find only `,v` files maintained by RCS, ignoring those maintained by CVS.

The other answers using `find -path` are probably better, but this is an alternative -- and for other purposes, `grep` regular expressions are more powerful than the shell patterns accepted by `find -path`.